# Association "is invalid" when model is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Club model and a Member model, which are associated through a Membership model. In other words

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members, :through => :memberships
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clubs, :through => :memberships
end
```

However, when I attempt to create a new member and add it to a club, I get an error saying that the club is invalid.

```
> club = Club.find(1)
> member = Member.new(:name => 'Member Name')
> member.clubs << club
> member.save
```

The `member.save` statement will return false. Looking at the member.errors.messages, I find

```
> member.errors.messages
@messages={:clubs=>["is invalid"]}
```

The really bizarre thing is that this does not happen for my Development environment (using sqlite3), but only on my EngineYard deployment using mySQL.

Comment: In addition to my answer below, are you sure that `club` was found and is valid on its own, prior to adding it to `member.clubs`?

Comment: Yes, the club is found and is valid. You are able to log into the web app as the club without any problems. It is only when the club tries to add a member that the problem occurs.

Comment: Also, the seed data for my demo clubs is loading fine. Therefore the association table is in place and working. It just won't accept any new associations.

Comment: Could be a db level validation issue? Can you post your members schema?

Comment: Jim Stewart was on target with his first comment: my club is actually NOT valid. See the answer I provided below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just figured out my own problem. My Club class contains a virtual attribute :password, which is used only when a club is created, and should be ignored otherwise. It turns out that due to a bug, the password is not being ignored otherwise and is being validated when the club association is saved. So Jim Stewart was correct in his comment: the club is actually NOT valid, even though I thought it was.

The reason the problem does not occur in development is that I have password validation turned off in my development environment, so I can test with simple passwords.

Comment: I encounter the exact same issue. I even tried `has_many :models, validate: false' but still fails to save. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a `memberships` table in both development and production (i.e., did you run `rake db:migrate` everywhere)?

You may also need to modify your models like this:

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :members, :through => :memberships
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :clubs, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :club
  belongs_to :member
end
```